# Porque recibo este error al enviar JSON desde AJAX a JAVA SPRING MVC?

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring

Buenas, hace dos días me estoy volviendo loco con este problema.

Este el objeto json enviado como ejemplo:

```
{"listado":
       [{"pos":0,"idfact":30,"idprod":1,"idremito":29,"cant":1,"descripadic":"","precio":55,"subtotal":55},{"pos":1,"idfact":30,"idprod":2,"idremito":29,"cant":2,"descripadic":"","precio":85,"subtotal":170},{"pos":2,"idfact":30,"idprod":4,"idremito":29,"cant":3,"descripadic":"","precio":63.5,"subtotal":190.5}]}
```

Este es el código de AJAX utilizado

```
$.ajax({
            "type":"post",
            "url":"agregarRenglonesFactura",
            "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            "dataType": 'json',
            "cache": false,
            "data": {"obj": JSON.stringify(obj)},
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                // here it is
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
            }
            }).done(function(data){

                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            });
```

El controlador de Java Spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping(value="agregarRenglonesFactura", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public String redAgregarRenglonesFactura(@RequestParam("obj") String objJson ) throws Exception{

     try{

         Gson gson = new Gson();

         ListadoDTO listado = gson.fromJson(objJson, ListadoDTO.class);

        Iterator<RenglonFacturaDTO> it = listado.getListadorenglon().iterator();

        System.out.println("*************************************** TAMAÑO LISTA ******************************************** : ");

        System.out.println("*************************************** TAMAÑO LISTA ******************************************** : " + listado.getListadorenglon().size());

        while(it.hasNext()){

            RenglonFacturaDTO renglonfacturadto = it.next();

        System.out.println("***************AGREGAR RENGLON*******************IDRENGLONREMITO: " + renglonfacturadto.getIdremito() + " CANTIDAD: " + renglonfacturadto.getCant());

        }

        return ("TAMAÑO LISTA:");
    } catch (Exception e){

            throw new Exception("ERROR :" + e.getMessage());
  }}
```

Y por último, el request devuelve un cod 200 ok, como si hubiera funcionado, pero haciendo debug no pasa por el controlador, ni tampoco devuelve nada. Y debajo arroja:

Error de lectura XML: no se encuentra el elemento
Ubicación: http://localhost:8080/cuentascorrientes/agregarRenglonesFactura
Número de línea 1, columna 1:

Answer (score 1):

Parece que tienes un par de errores, tanto en la generación de la petición como en el controlador.

**En la petición**
No es necesario que encapsules el objeto en otro objeto más, puedes enviar directamente el listado:

```
"data": JSON.stringify(obj)
```

**En el controlador**
Una de las maravillas de Spring es poder parsear directamente los JSON a clases de tu modelo, aprovéchalo y cambia el parámetro del método del controlador a:

```
@RequestBody ListadoDTO listado
```